# Conexión Insegura Windows 10 Firefox y Chrome en última actualización para mis servidores locales

Tags: firefox, windows10, chrome

He actualizado mis navegadores y no tengo accesos a mis servidores locales, supuestamente por error de Conexión insegura.

Adjunto capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Versión de Firefox

> 59.0.1 (64-bits)

VERSIÓN CHROME

> Versión 65.0.3325.162 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se debe a que **chrome** desde la version 63 (diciembre de 2017) y **firefox** desde febrero de 2018 puedes verificar [aqui](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/17/09/18/192227/chrome-to-force-domains-ending-with-dev-and-foo-to-https-via-preloaded-hsts), **obligan a todos los dominios .dev a implementar https**, por lo tanto si tienes acceso a tus web locales.

#### **Solución:**

**Cambiar todos tus dominios .dev que trabajas en localhost a .test para que no tengas este inconveniente.** 
En el caso del que muestras en la captura cambiarias test-course.dev por test-course.test